# Android export data to csv

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, export

I want to export some fields from a table in my SQLite database in `CSV` format. I'm using the library `opencsv-2.4`. 
Works, but all the columns of the table are stored in a single column of the spreadsheet instead must be separated. 
This is my method:

```
  File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");        
if (!exportDir.exists()) 
{
    exportDir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(exportDir, "csvname.csv");
try 
{
    file.createNewFile();                
    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table",null);
    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
    while(curCSV.moveToNext())
    {
       //Which column you want to exprort
        String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }
    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}
catch(Exception sqlEx)
{
    Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separator for your columns.

Use this syntax:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ",", "", "\n");
```

Instead of:

```
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

This sets a comma (**,**) as the field separator and a newline (**\n**) as the line terminator

Or simply

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ",");
```

This sets a comma (**,**) as the field separator.
Excel uses a semicolon (**;**).
Other software might use pipe (**|**) or tab (**\t**) or ...

Comment: it does not accept, it displays error and says to remove the arguments

Comment: I removed some arguments and used a simplified version.

Comment: Does this depend on opencsv version?  The docs [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html) say that ',' and '\n' are the default separator and line end, so I would have thought it worked as posted.

Comment: To choose your separator really depends on the software you are going to share the file with. The standard is "," - Excel breaks the rules (not only the rules), by using ";". It is although able to understand "\n" as the line terminator, no need to specify the MS-DOS line terminator ("\r\n").